# Error in Xray Rest API Request to execution cucumber Json result test in Jira

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, cucumber-java, jira-xray

I am trying to send api request using:

```
`curl --location 'https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v1/import/execution/cucumber' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer $token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '**jsonresulttest**'`
```

I am sending with the correct token
and adding the json result test for the body api request

I generated the json result test in TestRunner class:

```
@Service
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/resources",
        glue = "classpath:com.gth.automation",
        tags = "@GTH-25068",
        plugin = {"json:target/cucumber-report.json", "pretty","html:target/cucumber-reports"},
        monochrome = true,
        publish = false)
public class TestRunner {
}
```

Adding the result test json from the file target/cucumber-report.json.
but I am getting an error from Postman:

```
{
    "error": "Error creating Test Execution - Issue create failed! - assignee: Field 'assignee' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."
}
```

I think the structure that is generated in target/cucumber-report.json has a different structure than the Xray API call that is accepted to get.
I need help in figuring out how can I produce the correct json structure for the API request

```
**POST /rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/cucumber**
```

thanks.

I trying to send Correct API request to

```
POST /rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/cucumber/multipart
```

Comment: I have some questions in order to be able to help: 1- Are you using Cloud or Server version of Jira? 2- What framework/tool you are using to execute the tests and generate the results file? 3- Can you share the results file (after cleaning it of any sensible information)?

Comment: 1.2. I am using the cucumber framework to generate the result test in json formatt        
3..

Answer (score 0):

It seems a Jira configuration issue related to the screen configuration associated with Test Execution issues.
Please check with your Jira administrator that you can manually create Test Execution issues (you can try to create one by yourself) and that you see the "Assignee" field on the dialog.

[image: Test Execution issue creation dialog]

If you don't see it, then use the options on the creation dialog to see if you can add it.

[image]

If not, the project administrator can go to the project settings => Issues => Screens and then edit the corresponding Create and Edit issue screen that are associated to the Test Execution issue type.

[image]

Note: the "Assignee" should also appear on the view screen of Test Execution issues.

[image: Test Execution issue view screen]

Comment: Hello Sergio,
thank you for your answer, In my test execution issues there is QA Assignee and not

Comment: @shi, so you were able to solve it?

Comment: No, in my Jira project, I already have Assigne in test execution but we are calling this label, QA Assignee. Do you think this is the problem and I need to change it from QA Assignee to Assignee?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure; you can try it out and see if works. Assignee is a field that exists in Jira by default and usually don't change it..